# render json URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this bit of render code in my controller but now trying to figure the URL I need to use to see this json object. I been looking for a document but could not find one

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @current_builds_summaries }
end
```

Is there something I need to do in my routes file first?

I tried:

```
http://localhost:3000/current_builds_summaries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .js at the end of your link!

Format.json normally maps to that link ending!

Edit: the link to that controller action, that is.

Comment: Getting No route matches [GET] "/current_builds_summaries.js" and I tried with a .json ext and get No route matches [GET] "/current_builds_summaries.json"

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out! ;-) just use the URL of your controller action route

Comment: current_builds_summaries is not the name of the controller. That is just the variable I sent to it. The name of the controller is current_store_builds

Comment: I suppose you have that index action of the current_store_builds controller hooked up to a route in config/routes.rb, using that URL should work

Comment: It was an issue in my routes file. When I set the home controller to root I did not add a resource. Its not fixed. Thanks